# struct name followed by parens

Tags: rust

Can someone please tell me what these parens do after the name for a struct?

```
pub struct Bytes(Vec<u8>);
```

Is that inheritance? I thought Rust didn't have inheritance. I can't find any docs in the official Rust book for this syntax.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types. See also https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types and (in particular) https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction for doing this with a tuple of just one type, and why it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a typle struct, like this:

```
struct Color(i8, i8, i8);
```

you can get data from it:

```
struct Color(i8, i8, i8);

fn main() {
    let color = Color(1, 2, 25);
    println!("{}", color.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs). It has nothing to do with inheritance. Tuple structs have a name, but their fields don't.

Here is an example how you can create a `Bytes` value:

```
let b = Bytes(vec![44, 5, 27]);
```

And this is how you access the `Vec` inside:

```
println!("{:?}", b.0);
```